# Ошибка при получение данных из editText android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, activity

Я добавил это в приложение в mainActivity

`bundle.putString("phone",FragmentManager.findFragment<SecondFragment> (View(this)).view?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.phone_signup)?.text.toString())`

После этого у меня при вызове этого крашится приложения... из за чего это? В чем проблема?

Сам `editText` в **fragment_second.xml**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/phone_signup"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:hint="@string/phone"
    android:textColorHint="@color/grey"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:background="@drawable/input_text"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="85dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="phone"/>
```

Код **MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun toastMe(Str: String) {
        val myToast = Toast.makeText(this,Str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        myToast.show()
    }

    fun RegistrationCallFragment() {

        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString("phone", 
            FragmentManager.findFragment<SecondFragment>(View(this)).view?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.phone_signup)?.text.toString()
        )
        bundle.putString("email",
            FragmentManager.findFragment<SecondFragment>(View(this)).view?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.email_signup)?.text.toString()
        )
        bundle.putString("password",
            FragmentManager.findFragment<SecondFragment>(View(this)).view?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.pasword_signup)?.text.toString()
        )

        Registration_second.getNewInstance(args = bundle)
    }
}
```

код из фрагмента где я принимаю эти данные

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    //val extras = getIntent()?.getExtras();
    //if(extras != null) {
    //    val phone = extras.getString("phone", "")
    //    val email = extras.getString("email", "")
    //    val password = extras.getString("password", "")
    //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_registration_second, container, false)

    val phone = arguments?.getString("phone", "")
    val email = arguments?.getString("email", "")
    val password = arguments?.getString("password", "")
    Log.d("PHONE BLYAT", phone+email+password+"THis")
    print(phone+email+password)
    val activ = activity
    (activ as MainActivity).toastMe(phone.toString())
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_registration_second, container, false)
}
```

Log
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Логи падения нужно смотреть, а не гадать.

Comment: @Andrey Mihalev я добавил

Comment: @Andrey Mihalev я добавил

Answer (score 0):

Вот это

```
FragmentManager.findFragment<SecondFragment> (View(this))
```

Что-то совсем невнятное. Что вы хотели тут получить? Функция findFragment находит экземпляр фрагмента, который содержит переданную в параметр вьюшку. Причем вроде не любую вьюшку, а именно корневую вьюшку фрагмента, которая возвращается в onCreateView. Передавая ей заглушку из свежесозданной вьюшки, не прикнрепленной на активити и не связанной с фрагментом, какой вы ждете результат?

Вообще, какой смысл искать фрагмент? запомните его где-нибудь в поле активити после создания. Вы выложили фрагментированный бессвязный код, по нему тяжело сказать больше

Answer (score 0):

По всей видимости ваш фрагмент еще не запущен. Ну и вообще так никто не передает данные во фрагмент из активити. Обычно есть 2 пути:

- При создании фрагмента положить в аргументы нужный вам параметр в фрагмент. Хорошей практикой является делать во фрагменте статический метод вроде такого:

  ```
  companion object {

      private const val ARG_BLA_BLA = "bla_bla"

      fun createInstance(blabla: String): YourFragment =
          YourFragment().apply {
              arguments = bundleOf(ARG_BLA_BLA to blabla)
          }
  }
  ```

  И вызывать его в активити для создания вашего фрагмента.
- Если же вам нужно передавать какие-то параметры после создания фрагмента это делается так:

  1. Создаете интерфейс который реализует фрагмент. Например:

  `interface Interractor{`

  `fun putArgs(blabla:String)`

  `}`

  2. Создаете экземпляр этого интерфейса в вашей активити и приравниваете его экземпляру вашего фрагмента.
  3. Вызываете метод `putArgs(blabla:String)`  всякий раз когда вам необходимо положить какие-то аргументы в фрагмент.
  4. во фрагменте уже в реализованном методе реагируете на ваши аргументы.

Comment: Странно, так как приложение начало падать тогда когда я FragmentManager.findFragment<SecondFragment>(View(this)).view?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.phone_signup)?.text.toString()    то есть приложение падает из за того что я получаю данные из другого фрагмента.